# Abrir relatório em outra aba

Tags: java, html, html5, jasper

Preciso que o relatório, na hora que o usuário clique em um botão, execute em outra aba. Estou usando:

```
<p:commandButton  oncomplete="history.go(0)"   onclick="target = '_blank'"
  style="width: 200px;margin-top: 18px;float: right" type="submit" 
  value="Visualizar Relatório" ajax="false" update="form" actionListener="#
  {mbean_458_VendasGeral.gerarRelatorio('0')}">
```

Ele ate funciona, o problema é quando o usuário não coloca uma data ou seleciona uma loja, ai eu exibo uma mensagem pro usuário e  não gera o relatório , só que o programa abre isso em uma nova aba. Eu preciso q ele só abra o relatório em nova aba, as mensagens não. Como corrigir isso?

Segue codigo da loja :

```
 <div class="Container20 Responsive50" style="margin-left: 2px;">
                <div class="ContainerIndent">
                    <p:outputLabel style="#{mbean_458_VendasGeral.cor};margin-left: 5px;" value="Lojas"  />
                    <p:panelGrid id="t" columns="1" layout="grid" style="border:0px !important; background:none;" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
                        <p:selectCheckboxMenu filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"  widgetVar="someVarName" id="lojas" label="#{mbean_458_VendasGeral.selectLj}"  value="#{mbean_458_VendasGeral.loja}"  >
                            <f:selectItems  var="loja" itemValue="#{loja.codloj}" itemLabel="#{loja.codloj}" value="#{mbean_458_VendasGeral.lojas}"/>
                            <p:ajax oncomplete="PF('someVarName').show()"  update="t" listener="#{mbean_458_VendasGeral.selectLoja()}" /> 
                            <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" oncomplete="PF('someVarName').show()" listener="#{mbean_458_VendasGeral.selectLoja()}" update="t"/>

                        </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </div>
            </div>
```

segue codigo das datas :

```
<div class="Container35 Responsive50">
                <div class="ContainerIndent">
                    <p:outputLabel style="margin-left: 5px;#{mbean_458_VendasGeral.cor}" value="Período de Vendas" />
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" style="border:0px !important; background:none;" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
                        <p:calendar locale="pt_BR" onkeyup="Formatadata(this, event)" id="iniven" placeholder="Até" value="#{mbean_458_VendasGeral.iniven}" showOn="button" />

                        <p:calendar locale="pt_BR" onkeyup="Formatadata(this, event)" id="inifin" placeholder="Até" value="#{mbean_458_VendasGeral.finven}" showOn="button"/>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente substituindo:

```
onclick="target = '_blank'"
```

Por:

```
target = "_blank"
```

Comment: ele faz a mesma coisa, ou seja mesmo que nao execute o relatorio ele abre outra pagina trazendo minhas validacoes

Comment: Bom, então creio que o melhor seja você efetuar as duas validações (loja e data selecionados) em javascript/jquery, assim nem precisa enviar form para validar. Poderia postar os códigos do campos que precisa validar?

Comment: adicionei ali no codigo as datas e a loja obrigado desde ja

Comment: Mano do céu, eu conheço html e java, mas nunca usei jasper. Como ficam esses 3 blocos de código quando a página é carregada no navegador? Me mostre isso e eu lhe faço o script pra validar em javascript/jquery.

Comment: rsrs, explique nao entendi oq quis perguntar , vc quer ver o meu metido de gerar relatorio ??

Comment: Você postou o código que está no arquivo, eu quero ver esses mesmos elementos depois que o html é gerado, o código que aparece no navegador. Você tem essa página online? Ou só abra no navegador, salve a página como html e depois copie o código salvo aqui.

Comment: ta no ar so que so para os cliente, tem q ter usuaario e senha pra acessar

Comment: Então save a página (com CTRL+S) do navegador e cole aqui a parte dos elementos loja e data.